# How to solve usng temporary;using filesort using MySQL SELET SELECT UNION SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.id AS id,
          a.user_id AS user_id,
          aa.power * a.amount AS total_power,
          a.group_number AS group_number,
          a.amount AS total_amount,
          aa.type AS TYPE
   FROM units a
   JOIN unit_diagrams aa ON a.diagram_id = aa.id
   WHERE a.group_id = 0
     AND a.current_x = 1
     AND a.current_y = 1
     AND a.movement_start_time = 0
   UNION SELECT MIN(b.id) AS id,
                MIN(b.user_id) AS user_id,
                SUM(bb.power * b.amount) AS total_power,
                MAX(b.group_number) AS group_number,
                SUM(b.amount) AS total_amount,
                MIN(bb.type) AS TYPE
   FROM units b
   JOIN unit_diagrams bb ON b.diagram_id = bb.id
   WHERE b.group_id != 0
     AND b.current_x = 1
     AND b.current_y = 1
     AND b.movement_start_time = 0
   GROUP BY b.group_id) hello
ORDER BY group_number ASC,
         total_power DESC
LIMIT 10,
      10
```

When I run explain on it I get:

```
+----------------------------------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+--+
|                                  |              |            |        |                                                       |                                 |      |                                            |      |                                              |  |
+----------------------------------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+--+
|                                  |              |            |        |                                                       |                                 |      |                                            |      |                                              |  |
|                                  |              |            |        |                                                       |                                 |      |                                            |      |                                              |  |
| 1                                | PRIMARY      | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                                                  | NULL                            | NULL | NULL                                       | 123  | Using filesort                               |  |
| 2                                | DERIVED      | aa         | index  | PRIMARY,unit_diagrams_idx_id_power_type               | unit_diagrams_idx_id_power_type | 12   | NULL                                       | 6    | Using index                                  |  |
| 2                                | DERIVED      | a          | ref    | current_x,select_units_on_loc,units_idx_id_x_y_tim... | select_units_on_loc             | 20   | const,const,const,const,gpar_game_db.aa.id | 5    | Using index                                  |  |
| 3                                | UNION        | b          | ref    | current_x,select_units_on_loc,units_idx_id_x_y_tim... | current_x                       | 8    | const,const                                | 93   | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |  |
| 3                                | UNION        | bb         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,unit_diagrams_idx_id_power_type               | PRIMARY                         | 4    | gpar_game_db.b.diagram_id                  | 1    |                                              |  |
| NULL                             | UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL    | NULL                                                  | NULL                            | NULL | NULL                                       | NULL |                                              |  |
|  4                         | -2,027.1     |            |        |                                                       |                                 |      |                                            |      |                                              |  |
| |              |            |        |                                                       |                                 |      |                                            |      |                                              |  |
+----------------------------------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+--+
```

I have this indexes on both tables units and user_diagrams:

```
ALTER TABLE `units`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `current_x` (`current_x`,`current_y`),
  ADD KEY `to_x` (`to_x`,`to_y`),
  ADD KEY `select_units_on_loc` (`group_id`,`movement_start_time`,`current_y`,`current_x`,`diagram_id`,`id`,`user_id`,`group_number`,`amount`),
  ADD KEY `units_idx_id_x_y_time_id` (`group_id`,`current_x`,`current_y`,`movement_start_time`,`diagram_id`);


ALTER TABLE `units`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `unit_diagrams`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `unit_diagrams_idx_id_power_type` (`id`,`power`,`type`);


ALTER TABLE `unit_diagrams`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The table is not very big yet as I am just testing the app now, but even now the query is slower than other parts of my app. If I do profile it executed in about 0.007-0.011 sec, which it too slow, and I am sure this is because of the temporary/filesort. How to optimise this query?

Comment: Do you really need `UNION`? This needs to do a `DISTINCT`, `UNION ALL`  is usually more efficient.

Comment: @dnoeth You are right, I do not. I ran this with UNION ALL and it seemed to decrease execution time a bit and did not change my desired results.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Hm, so do you mean that "Using temporary;" does not slow down UNION queries?

Comment: `do you mean that "Using temporary;" does not slow down UNION queries?` - union must sort both tables in order to remove duplicates. Your query actually sorts the whole result twice - first time for UNION needs, and second time because of ORDER BY clause in your query. UNION ALL does not need the sort, so usually is faster than union.The filesort is a separate topic, Mysql uses filesort if the result does not fit in memory. Since you are using ORDER BY clause, then you will not get rid of it (add more memory).